# Word 2010 Beta - Vertically center content on a single page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office-2010-beta, microsoft-word-2010

I am writing a paper using Word 2010 Beta and need to horizontally and vertically center my title page. I can horz. center but when I do a vertical center it applies that to the entire document. How do I do a vertical center on just a single page?

Comment: Stick some newlines in? That's what I do :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a text box, then click on Format - then Align. It will give you an option for the middle of the page.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the "accepted" way to do it but it works for me!

Answer (score 5):

Answer #0 is the Winner!!, but

1. You need to highlight the text you want to vertically center.
2. Then click the arrow pointing south west in the page layout ribbon to open the page layout window.
3. Then in the vertical alignment drop down box select `Center`.
4. Below that, you see the apply to `this section`, change that to `selected Text` (assuming you selected the text you want to center first).
5. This will center the text on the page and put anything after the selected text on the next page, it does an automatic break.

Comment: +1 this seems the better answer. Also the text box may not be exactly centrally positioned itself

Comment: Most Appropriate answer

Answer (score 3):

I think the "accepted" way is to create a section out of the title page (continuous section break after the title page) and apply the vertical alignment to that section only (Center to section one and top to section two), but I don't see any reason why MrStatic's solution doesn't do the job just as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the accepted answer being the "best" answer.

On the Page Layout tab of the ribbon control, click the little button that points to about 5:00 (lower right hand corner in his pic).

[image: Page Setup]

This brings up the Page Setup dialog. At this point, select the **Layout** tab and select **Center** from the Vertical Alignment drop down list.

[image: Select center from Vertical Alignment]

Comment: This will apply to whole the document :-\